# Arduino Loop Break

Tags: java, loops, arduino, break

at school currently we are creating a robot using an arduino that can be controlled by Bluetooth, using Thunkable. Currently the app sends the arduino characters that the arduino will recognise and will follow an IF STATEMENT. I've created a Figure 8 command, which works as of now, but it's stuck in loop and won't stop, even if the STOP button is pressed. I made sure to set x = false in the off if statement, but I don't think it's working with the current code. I've tried using a break, but to no avail. All I want to do, is stop the loop from continuing, using the off command. Any help would be appreciated.

```
//L293D
// connect motor controller pins to Arduino digital pins
// motor one
char input; 
boolean x = false;
boolean timer = true;
int enA = 12;
int in1 = 11;
int in2 = 10;
// motor two
int enB = 8;
int in3 = 9;
int in4 = 7;

void setup()
{
  // set all the motor control pins to outputs
  pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);


  Serial.begin(9600);   
  Serial.println(">> START <<");
}
void demoOne()
{
  if(Serial.available() >= 0)  
  {      
    input = Serial.read();
    if(input=='k')  
    {  
      Serial.println("ON");  
      digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
      analogWrite(enA, 200);
      analogWrite(enB, 200);  
    }  
    else if(input == 'q')
    {
      Serial.println("REVERSE");
      digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);
      analogWrite(enA, 200);
      analogWrite(enB, 200); 
    }
    else if(input == 'l')
    {
      x = false;
      Serial.println("OFF");
      digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
    }
    else if(input == 'c')
    {
      Serial.println("CIRCLE MODE");
      digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
      analogWrite(enA, 200);
      analogWrite(enB, 200);
    }
    // THIS IS THE HIGHLIGHTED CODE THAT I NEED HELP WITH
    else if(input == 'i')
    {
      for(x == true; x = true;)
      {
        if(x == false)
        {
          break;
        }
      Serial.println("FIGURE EIGHT MODE");
      digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
      analogWrite(enA, 200);
      analogWrite(enB, 200);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
      analogWrite(enA, 200);
      analogWrite(enB, 200);
      delay(1000);

      }
    }

    else if(input == 'r')
    {
      Serial.println("CIRCLE MODE");
      digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
      analogWrite(enA, 200);
      analogWrite(enB, 200);
    }
    else  
    {  
      Serial.println("NO INPUT");  
      Serial.println(input); 
      delay(1000); 
    }  
  }

  /* this function will run the motors in both directions at a fixed speed
  // turn on motor A
  // digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
  // digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
  // set speed to 200 out of possible range 0~255
  // analogWrite(enA, 200);
  // turn on motor B
  // digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
  // digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
  // set speed to 200 out of possible range 0~255
  analogWrite(enB, 200);
  delay(2000);
  // now change motor directions
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);  
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, HIGH); 
  delay(2000);
  // now turn off motors
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2, LOW);  
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, LOW); */
}
void demoTwo()
{
  /* this function will run the motors across the range of possible speeds
  // note that maximum speed is determined by the motor itself and the operating voltage
  // the PWM values sent by analogWrite() are fractions of the maximum speed possible 
  // by your hardware
  // turn on motors
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);  
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, HIGH); 
  // accelerate from zero to maximum speed
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  {
    analogWrite(enA, i);
    analogWrite(enB, i);
    delay(20);
  } 
  // decelerate from maximum speed to zero
  for (int i = 255; i >= 0; --i)
  {
    analogWrite(enA, i);
    analogWrite(enB, i);
    delay(20);
  } 
  // now turn off motors
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2, LOW);  
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, LOW); */ 
}

void loop()
{
  demoOne();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arduino loops are not exactly the same as loops you might write in a normal piece of code. What I like to do for my arduino programs is to declare a global boolean variable called "isOn" or something similar. If you surround the entire loop with an if statement checking if this is true, then you will be able to shut off your figure 8 loop by changing the value of this global variable so that your loop stops running. Break statements won't work on the entirety of this loop as you might expect from other programming you have done in the past.